# Twitter API: Headers to post a retweet from multiple accounts

Tags: python, node.js, go, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to build an app to send a retweet automatically with multiple accounts of a specific tweet so I just wanted to know what are the exactly headers/information should I attach in order to send the retweet from every account, because since the retweet function needs the user to be authenticated then I was thinking to authenticate the users manually with a Sign-in with Twitter button or is there another way to sign the users and save the tokens or the information needed to send the retweet?

I'm the owner of those accounts so if I can sign in using user/pwd, I can do it.

I'm already testing some services I built in my NodeJS server but since I'm not really sure about how to accomplish this task, I prefer to ask before continue.

Kind regards!

Comment: why so many language tags? Each language has their own package(s) for interacting with twitter. For example a package for Go. https://github.com/dghubble/go-twitter  where you need the consumer information and secret information.  You'll have to get that information for each account, store it somewhere, and use that information to create one programatic client for account.

Comment: I was misunderstanding the flow of the oauth and the data needed to send retweets but I just figured out, thank you any way. By the way, I set python and go as tags because I was also testing with those languages.